# Bootstrap multi row elements

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am working on a design for a website and practicing bootstrap in the meantime, so I am rather new to it. Now, I understand the grid division into 12 columns and then layering of elements into multiple rows and separating by column span. The question I have is how can I handle elements that span multiple rows next to the elements that span less.

[Desired Layout Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoPhb.jpg)

Now, on this example image, how would I accomplish the stacking of the 3 x 4 and the 3x2 and 3x3 blocks? Also, the elements shouldn't be resized vertically.

Since I am relatively new to Bootstrap and responsive design in general, I am open for other frameworks and/or workarounds.

Comment: show some code here what u did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this needs quite a lot of nested containers to get your desired effect but it is all possible.

The heights of some of the elements is a little bit off but once content is filled out, it should look fine.

Below is a working example

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div div {
  border: 1px solid #444;
}
div div div {
  border: 1px solid #888;
}
div div div div {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1">1x1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">1x1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">1x1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">1x1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">1x1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">1x1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">1x1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">1x1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">1x1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">1x1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">1x1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">1x1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="row">
        3x2
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        3x3
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          3x4
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              3x2
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              3x2
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              6
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              6
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                  1
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                  1
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                  1
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                  1
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                  1
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                  1
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                  1
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                  1
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                  1
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like below. It is not complete HTML, but it can give you an idea as to how you can use the horizontal and vertical bootstrap grids (basically through nesting):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='form-horizontal'>
      <!--First Row-->
      <div class='form-group'>
        <div class='col-md-1'></div>
        <div class='col-md-1'></div>
        <div class='col-md-1'></div>
        <div class='col-md-1'></div>
        <div class='col-md-1'></div>
        <div class='col-md-1'></div>
        <div class='col-md-1'></div>
        <div class='col-md-1'></div>
        <div class='col-md-1'></div>
        <div class='col-md-1'></div>
        <div class='col-md-1'></div>
        <div class='col-md-1'></div>
      </div>
      <!--Second Row-->
      <div class='form-group'>
        <div class='col-md-3'>
          <div class='form-group'></div>
          <div class='form-group'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-3'>
          <div class='form-group'></div>
          <div class='form-group'></div>
          <div class='form-group'></div>
          <div class='form-group'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-6'>
          <div class='form-group'>
            <div class='col-md-6'>
              <div class='form-group'></div>
              <div class='form-group'></div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-6'>
              <div class='form-group'></div>
              <div class='form-group'></div>
            </div>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```